# How do you set controlsource to a link passed from openargs

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I'm building a help form which has a webbrowser control to display the help.html file. I'm using openargs from the calling form and what I've tried so far keeps coming up with the address is not valid. I know the file string works because I can type it directly into the webbrowser's control source on the property sheet and it works perfectly. I've spent about 3 hours trying to come up with different methods and the openargs seems the simplest if I could only get it to work.

Calling form:

```
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frm_CS_Help", OpenArgs:="=""" & "C:\Users\bamad\Documents\CSHelp.html#DROPBOX"""
```

The Help form:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

Dim strPath As String

strPath = Me.OpenArgs
WebBrowser43.ControlSource = strPath
```

The string that works when I type it directly on to the controlsource property for the webbrowser control is:

```
="C:\Users\bamad\Documents\CSHelp.html#DROPBOX"
```

Any help pointing me in the right direction would be much appreciated. Cheers

Comment: I can't replicate this. So, as you access a user folder, it has probably to do with some missing rights.

Comment: The path works perfectly directly from the property sheet but not VBA using control source. If I use a different method like set browser = webbrowser43.object and browser.navigate path it will display the file OK if I don't include the ID tag #DROPBOX. I just don't know enough Access to get that way to work yet. Application.followhyperlink works as well without the tag, with the tag I get address is not valid but if I select back it takes me to the DROPBOX ID location in the document so I don't think it's permissions.

Comment: Then the issue is `#DROPBOX`, not Access, neither your code.

Comment: Aaaagh! What an idiot. Thank you. That's what comes from working way past your bedtime!

Comment: Have in mind also, that the current web browser control is using the Internet Explorer engine, not Chromium of Edge. A new web browser control using this engine has been announced by Microsoft for this year but not yet published.

Comment: Try: `OpenArgs:="='C:\Users\bamad\Documents\CSHelp.html#DROPBOX'"`. With or without `#DROPBOX`. I find it simpler and easier to read using apostrophe delimiters. Also, the concatenation is not necessary.